# Delphi byte array leading zeroes (?empty? spaces in array)

Tags: arrays, delphi, hex, apdu

I'm trying to add 00 for each byte array element that is missing, to explain it better, if `lenght` of an array is 20 and the string fills only 9 spaces (reversed), I need the rest 11 spaces to be `00`. An example will explain it better.

This is my code so far:

```
   var
      dateAndTimeOfIssue, taxPayerId: Tarray<Byte>;
      dateOfIssueMS, DOIReversed: int64;
   begin
      dateOfIssueMS := StrToInt64(MilliSecondsBetween(f.InvoiceRequest.dateAndTimeOfIssue, 
                       UnixDateDelta).ToString);
      ReverseBytes(@(dateofIssueMS), @(DOIReversed), SizeOf(dateofIssueMS));
      setLength(dateAndTimeOfIssue, 8);
      Move(DOIReversed, dateAndTimeOfIssue[0], SizeOf(DOIReversed));
      // result of this byte array casted into hex string is  
         '0000313B23048B31' // which is correct

      setlength(taxPayerId, 20);
      taxPayerId := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(F.MyCompany.taxpayerId);
      // result of this byte array casted into hex string is
         '303231313331363832' // and I need it to be 
         '0000000000000000000000303231313331363832'
```

What I am actually trying to achieve is add multiple byte arrays into one final array that will be sent to SmartCard, these are just the 2 arrays here for example (I'm using hexadecimal strings only to represent what the bytes look like because I have a full example of how it should be). APDU Commands are weird, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you request... Maybe what you are looking for is IntToHex(Number, Digits)?

Comment: @fpiette Nah, I think he's looking for StringOfChar.  But implementing such a function is relatively trivial compared to what he's working with.  He's definitely out of his depth. @q1werty : By the way, `setlength(taxPayerId, 20)` is pointless. The array is allocated by `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes`.  The array allocated by SetLength gets destroyed immediately after. Unless the compiler somehow manage to make optimisation that prevents that... But still, the point stands, that SetLength is unnecessary.

Comment: Why don''t you simply set the length of your final array first and then copy the desired data with appropriate offset to keep the leading zeroes? Note you might also fill the resized array with zeroes first before copying the data if this isn't already done so automatically during resizing. I'm not used to working with generic arrays.

Comment: Use `FillChar` for this

Comment: Maybe my question was a little bit unclear, my bad. As @fpiette has said, I was definitely out of my scope here, all I actually needed is a simple buffer as Tom stated in answer below, was just burnt out I guess. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual tax payer Id seems to be 9 characters: '021131682'. For a total length of 20 bytes you need 11 null bytes first in the `ArrTaxPayerId` array. So, with `BufferSize=20`, `StrTaxPayerId='021131682'` you can set the initial length of `ArrTaxPayerId`:

```
SetLength(ArrTaxPayerId, BufferSize - Length(StrTaxPayerId);
```

That will now hold 11 null bytes. Then you concatenate it with the bytes of the actual tax payer ID:

```
ArrTaxPayerId := ArrTaxPayerId + TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StrTaxPayerId);
```

Then the final step is to convert the 20 byte `ArrTaxPayerId` to hex representation using `BinToHex()` which you already have the code for.

When I tried the above I got a result of `0000000000000000000000303231313331363832`

Comment: Exactly what I needed, simple solution. Thank you very much!